# have troubles with understanding the name of scenario in validation in Yii

Tags: php, yii

Second hour I'm triyng to understand which name of scenario I have to use in validation rule. I've already read a lot of googling pages and helps but everywhere they use some names which I don't know where they got. I show an example:
I have model with columns username and password and rule for it:

```
array('username, password', 'required'),
array('username', 'min'=>5, 'on'=>'What_name_I_have_to_use_here'),
```

Then I have controller with name UsersController and action actionRegister():

```
 class UsersController extends Controller
 {
      public function actionRegister()
      {
           $myModel = new Model();
           if ($myModel->validate('What_should_I_write_here'))
                $this->render('registrationConfirm');                  
      }
 }
```

I also have views: registrationForm and registrationConfirm. 
Tell me please what should I write in place of my questions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario is well described in documentation
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh3

In short. For example you have 2 forms: X and Y connected with one model. You have specified validators in model. By specifing `on` you can define to what form is.
In form X you want to have input name `sample` required, but in form Y it mustn't be filled. It means you have to specify it

```
array('sample', 'required', 'on'=>'Y'),
```

Comment: I've read that link several times, but I don't understand why it doesn't work for me. In my case, I have view with name registrationForm, so I write 'on'=>'registrationForm'm but it doesn't work. It works only without 'on' but then I cann't use another view because it validate another form with same rules

Comment: In many forms are validating with these same rules, `on` is not needed

Comment: ahh, ok, I made everything. I could add $nameOfModel->scenario = 'scenarioName';

Comment: needed needed, if you use the same model, controller and diff actions